# SQL instead of trigger and update

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers, sql-update

I have these tables:

- Movie ( mID, title, year, director )
- Reviewer ( rID, name )
- Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate )

and some views:

- View `LateRating` contains movie ratings after January 20, 2011. The view contains the movie ID, movie title, number of stars, and rating date.

  ```
  create view LateRating as 
    select distinct R.mID, title, stars, ratingDate 
    from Rating R, Movie M 
    where R.mID = M.mID 
    and ratingDate > '2011-01-20'
  ```
- View `HighlyRated` contains movies with at least one rating above 3 stars. The view contains the movie ID and movie title.

  ```
  create view HighlyRated as 
    select mID, title 
    from Movie 
    where mID in (select mID from Rating where stars > 3)
  ```
- View `NoRating` contains movies with no ratings in the database. The view contains the movie ID and movie title.

  ```
  create view NoRating as 
    select mID, title 
    from Movie 
    where mID not in (select mID from Rating)
  ```

Here's my data set : https://prod-c2g.s3.amazonaws.com/db/Winter2013/files/viewmovie.sql

I'm asked to write an instead-of trigger that enables updates to the stars attribute of view LateRating.Here's my approach.

```
CREATE trigger update_LateRating_title INSTEAD OF 
UPDATE OF stars ON LateRating
BEGIN
  UPDATE Rating SET stars = stars - 2 
  WHERE Rating.mID = old.mID 
  AND Rating.mID IN (SELECT stars FROM Rating WHERE stars > 2);
END;
```

It gives almost right answer but there is only one wrong row that being  201 101 4 2011-01-27.4 should be 2.What is wrong?

Comment: Upload your dataset to some place where it could be downloaded without giving out a mobile number to depositfiles. Is it really 2.44 Kb? Then just dump it as sql (`.dump` command in sqlite3 client) and maybe even paste it into your question (if it's a bit large, put it on pastebin or something like that)

Comment: @AntonKovalenko I edited link.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko Also Do you have MSN account?I have couple of similar questions.

Comment: You have two entries in your rating for movie 101, one with 2: `201|101|2|2011-01-22` and another with 4: `201|101|4|2011-01-27`. Is one of them wrong? Only you could know how they got there, but views and triggers are probably irrelevant. (No MSN account. Use email from my network profile, but I'm going to request a compensation for this kind of support)

Comment: @AntonKovalenko No,they are not wrong.A user reviewed movie twice.That's all.The wrong part is it has 4 stars so 4 - 2 should turn 2 but it doesn't :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your `WHERE` condition:

```
...AND Rating.mID IN (SELECT stars FROM Rating WHERE stars > 2)
```

It states that `Rating.mID` should be among values of `stars` selected from rating. I'm unsure what was intended here. Let's assume you want to decrease the number of stars by 2 for any attempt to modify stars (that's weird: you're turning queries which  would *increase* stars into some unrelated queries) if the *original* number of stars in *that* line of `Rating` table was greater than 2.

```
CREATE trigger update_LateRating_stars INSTEAD OF 
UPDATE OF stars ON LateRating
BEGIN
  UPDATE Rating SET stars = stars - 2 
  WHERE Rating.mID = old.mID 
  AND Rating.stars > 2;
END;
```

Again, there are many possible interpretations of what you want, and
they all are more or less *weird*: `mID` field in `LateRating` is not
enough to identify the original record in `Rating` (maybe `rID` and
`mID` together would be enough, if you don't allow the same reviewer to
hold different opinions on the same movie simultaneously).